# equalsIgnoreCase on a String array?

Tags: java

I am trying to write an if statement that checks each of the indexes of a String array.

The array is

```
private static final String[] letterGrades = {"A","AB","B","BC","C","CD","D","F"};
```

and I am trying to write the if statement something like

```
if(grade != letterGrades[0].equalsIgnoreCase() | grade != letterGrades[1].equalsIgnoreCase() | ... | grade != letterGrades[7].equalsIgnoreCase();){
//statements to run
}
```

and it obviously does not want to work. I'm curious how to get this to work as I would like to use the array, if possible.

Comment: `if(!letterGrades[0].equalsIgnoreCase(grade ) || ...{}`

Comment: you need to correct the syntax of the equalsIgnorecase method call first        Syntax:

Here is the syntax of this method:

public boolean equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString)

Answer (score 2):

You can try a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < letterGrades.length(); i++) {
    if (grade.equalsIgnoreCase(letterGrades[i]))
        ...
}
```

**Note** the way `equalsIgnoreCase` is called:

```
string1.equalsIgnoreCase(string2)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
letterGrades[0].equalsIgnoreCase(grade) for comparison

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)